# Disable window scroll when scrolling an overflowed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, scrollbar

I got an element with a vertical scrollbar via `overflow: auto`. When I scroll vertically inside it and reach the bottom, the window starts scrolling instead, due to the page content being longer than the height of the window. Can I disable this behavior?

```
// CSS
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: auto;
}

// HTML 
<div id="container">
   <div>Foo</div>
   ...
</div>

// Other content, stretching out the page vertically, 
// forcing a scrollbar on the window
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/zimabuco/1/

Comment: Why the down vote? Completely legitimate question.. At least post your reasoning.

Comment: Might be that you didn't also post your code.

Comment: Probably just someone seen a sentence of text and downvoted without reading it. You may want to put a cut down version of your HTML and CSS directly in the question though to help the question stand on it's own in the event the JSBin link was to break... then I would probably counter one of those downvotes for you

Comment: A simple solution would be to set overflow of the body to hidden when hovering the div. More elegant might be to listen to the mousewheel and prevent it's default action (scroll event can't be cancelled) in a case the div is hovered and have been scrolled to the bottom already.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the overflow of the body to hidden when the container is being hovered seems to work well.

```
$('div#container').mouseenter(function(event) {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}).mouseleave(function(event) {
    $('body').css('overflow', '');
});
```

See the following example, you'll see the scrollbar disappear when the div is hovered.
Example http://jsbin.com/sihihewi/3/edit

Answer (score 1):

This will disable the window to scroll when you hover over the list:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#container").hover(function(){

    $('html, body').css({
    'overflow': 'hidden',
    'height': '100%'
    })

  });

});
```